# Input text to move to next line when the width of the parent component is reached

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an issue where I can not figure out how to make my input fall down to a second line when I reach the max width of my container - it simply keeps scrolling towards the right.

```js
<form>
   <input autocomplete="off" className ="nice-border large" type="title" name="name" placeholder={this.state.description} />                          
</form>
```

CSS:

```css
.form-section input {

    width:100%;
    padding:5px;
    padding-top:10px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "word-wrap:break-word" in your css instead of "overflow-wrap: break-word".

Comment: Thank you Abhay but unfortunately this does not make a difference.